# Files deleted after rebase with git, how to recover?

Tags: git

I had some files on my project which rebase deleted. I did not commit anything.
I lost some important files, how can I recover them?

Comment: Git rebase doesn't normally run if you have modifications in your working directory.  What commands did you type and what does git status report?

Comment: Git fetch from remote / Git rebase

Comment: Are you mid-rebase?  What does `git status` show?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`git reflog` works wonders in such situations: simply use `git reflog` and note few recent commits that were active. Then use `git checkout commit_id` to checkout to any particular commit. Most likely, you need previous commit (current one is one you have screwed up).

Also, if you rebase was not committed yet, you can abort it with `git rebase --abort`.
If it was committed, you can simply kill last commit with `git reset --hard HEAD~`.

Comment: I thin you mean `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`.  HEAD~ doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: you are a lifesaver

Comment: This helped this get out of a tight situation. Thanks for this!

Comment: indeed a live saver. thanks for this!

Comment: I'd like to also add, you can use this to quickly check if commit_id has the files you thought you deleted: 
`git ls-tree -r --name-only $commit_id`. And yes, you are a true lifesaver!